# Moving excel data to an already existing word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

This is my third day of using VBA. I am currently working a 3 month contract for this company and have figured out how to automatically transfer data from excel to a new word document (a process they have wanted for years). I also found out how to open an existing word document from excel.

The thing is, I haven't worked out how to transfer data from excel to an existing word document.

Below is the code I am trying to write for the above reason. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Any and all answers would be greatly appreciated :)

```
Sub CopyRangeToWord()
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Set wordApp = GetObject("C:\Users\CoffeeFuelsMeNow\Documents\Ladedadeda\Testplate.dotx")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents
objWord.Visible = True
Range("A1:B10").Copy
 With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
       'All formatting goes here
    .Paste
    .Font.Name = "broadway"
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True
     .Font.Allcaps = True
     .Font.Size = 20
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please say what you want to achieve? Keep the question straight to the point

Comment: @eithed Sorry, that was the coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly fine for me: It adds the rows to the document over and over again as a table if i execute the code

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc =objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\schmidmath\Documents\test1.docx")

Range("A1:B10").Copy

With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
   'All formatting goes here
   .Paste
   .Font.Name = "broadway"
   .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
   .Font.Bold = True
   .Font.Italic = True
   .Font.Allcaps = True
   .Font.Size = 20    
End With
objWord.Visible = True
```

Comment: I've just tried to use this code and Excel spent a bit too long thinking about it. Am I still using Sub CopyRangeToWord() or do I need a different one?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. My word is playing up. This has helped

Answer (score 0):

Below modified code works at my end, test it and let me know if it suffice your requirement.

```
Sub CopyRangeToWord()
 Dim objWord
 Dim objDoc

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set wordApp = GetObject("C:\Users\CoffeeFuelsMeNow\Documents\Ladedadeda\Testplate.dotx")
Set obj­Doc = objWord.Documents

objWord.Visible = True
Range("A1:B10").Copy
 With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
       'All formatting goes here
    .Paste
    .Font.Name = "broadway"
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Font.Allcaps = True
    .Font.Size = 10
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So it does work but it opens a new word document. I need it to open an already created word document. I appreciate your help.